# Enter data from 10 textboxes, but do NOT submit empty textboxes values into cells (using excel vba userform)

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I will like to enter data from a ~10 textbox userform into Excel sheet only for the textboxes that are filled out.

I currently have the code to populate the cells from userform and it works but if the user does not fill out the rest of textboxes it still inputs these blank data entries.

**Current State:**

[image: Partial Textbox]
[image: All Data Entered]

**Future State:**
Only 2 ROWS FILLED...

[image: OnlyPartial Data Entered]

How can I tell the code to say if any of the fields in the textboxes 1-10 are empty do not enter... only enter the textboxes filled in under this RMA# AND Customer Name??

Thank you!

This is the code currently (thanks to the help of previous questions):

```
                Private Sub EnterButton_Click()
                
                
                
                           
                If TB1.Value = "" Then
               
                Else
                
                        Worksheets("RMA Tracker").Activate
                        Dim i As Long
                    
                    
                    For i = 1 To 10
                        
                        Dim lastrow As Long ' should put a data type with dim statements
                             
                        lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
                        lastrow = lastrow + 1
                        
                      
                       
                        Cells(lastrow, 1) = RecForm.Controls("RMATB").Value 
                        Cells(lastrow, 2) = RecForm.Controls("CustCB").Value
                        Cells(lastrow, 3) = RecForm.Controls("TB" & i).Value
                        Cells(lastrow, 4) = RecForm.Controls("SNTB" & i).Value
                        Cells(lastrow, 5) = RecForm.Controls("ReceiveTB").Value
                             
                Next i
                        
                 
                 
                 
                 
                
                End If
                            
                ActiveWorkbook.Save
                
                 
                Call resetform
                
                End Sub



        Sub resetform()
                
                
                RMATB.Value = ""
                CustCB.Value = ""
                TB1.Value = ""
                SNTB1.Value = ""
                TB2.Value = ""
                SNTB2.Value = ""
                TB3.Value = ""
                SNTB3.Value = ""
                TB4.Value = ""
                SNTB4.Value = ""
                TB5.Value = ""
                SNTB5.Value = ""
                TB6.Value = ""
                SNTB6.Value = ""
                TB7.Value = ""
                SNTB7.Value = ""
                TB8.Value = ""
                SNTB8.Value = ""
                TB9.Value = ""
                SNTB9.Value = ""
                TB10.Value = ""
                SNTB10.Value = ""
                
                ReceiveTB = ""
                
                'sets focus on that first textbox again
                RecForm.RMATB.SetFocus
                
                
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop, add a check to see if the entries are not blank.  Something like this:

```
   For i = 1 To 10
       If Trim(RecForm.Controls("TB" & i).Value) <> "" And Trim(ecForm.Controls("SNTB" & i).Value) <> "" Then
            Dim lastrow As Long ' should put a data type with dim statements
                 
            lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            lastrow = lastrow + 1
            
            Cells(lastrow, 1) = RecForm.Controls("RMATB").Value
            Cells(lastrow, 2) = RecForm.Controls("CustCB").Value
            Cells(lastrow, 3) = RecForm.Controls("TB" & i).Value
            Cells(lastrow, 4) = RecForm.Controls("SNTB" & i).Value
            Cells(lastrow, 5) = RecForm.Controls("ReceiveTB").Value
       End If
   Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

A second option would be to exit the For when you find the first empty textbox, something like this:

```
   For i = 1 To 10
       If Trim(RecForm.Controls("TB" & i).Value) = "" And Trim(ecForm.Controls("SNTB" & i).Value) = "" Then 
            GoTo MyNextCode 
        End If
        Dim lastrow As Long ' should put a data type with dim statements
                 
        lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lastrow = lastrow + 1
            
        Cells(lastrow, 1) = RecForm.Controls("RMATB").Value
        Cells(lastrow, 2) = RecForm.Controls("CustCB").Value
        Cells(lastrow, 3) = RecForm.Controls("TB" & i).Value
        Cells(lastrow, 4) = RecForm.Controls("SNTB" & i).Value
        Cells(lastrow, 5) = RecForm.Controls("ReceiveTB").Value
    Next i
MyNextCode:
...
```

This won't be much of a difference for this amount of controls but if you'd have more controls this method would exit upon the first empty one, thus preventing the code from having to go through all (in this case) controls... .
Another benefit to this solution is that you prevent to have e.g. PN1, PN2 and then all of a sudden PN5 (don't know if that is relevant here of course...).
From experience I know that if you have a lot of data to go through you'll be happier using this second option, option1 is great for the amount of data you have though and would work perfectly for a large amount of data or controls as well albeit slower...

Comment: Instead of `GoTo MyNextCode` use `Exit For`.

Comment: @Brian Is there a significant difference between doing Exit For rather than GoTo?

Comment: It accomplishes the same thing, I suppose, but why not use the statement that exists for this purpose?  Further, most developers frown upon using the archaic GoTo statement for any reason.  There are a few use cases for GoTo but this would not be one of them.